# Trying to clear an array with only one occurance

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

So here's the situation : i got an array who contain message between users, ->

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 17
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 2
            [date] => 2020-02-19 01:03:50
            [content] => yo !!
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 18
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 2
            [date] => 2020-02-19 01:03:50
            [content] => yo !!
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 16
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 2
            [date] => 2020-02-19 01:03:48
            [content] => yo
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 15
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 1
            [date] => 2020-02-19 01:03:44
            [content] => kk
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 14
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 3
            [date] => 2020-02-19 01:03:27
            [content] => hey
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 13
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 2
            [date] => 2020-02-19 01:03:22
            [content] => salut !
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 12
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 1
            [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:50
            [content] => yo ?
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 11
            [id_user_sending] => 3
            [id_user_receiving] => 4
            [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:27
            [content] => hey dernier test !
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 10
            [id_user_sending] => 2
            [id_user_receiving] => 4
            [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:17
            [content] => yo eksjsjs !
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 9
            [id_user_sending] => 1
            [id_user_receiving] => 4
            [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:05
            [content] => salut !
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

)
```

THE ID OF USER which connected is 4 
I want clear this array with only one occurence for making a chat list with only one field by user (id 4) independently of how message there is between them.

So i code two function wheres i got à problem ---->

```
function is_not_yet_in_array($arraymult, $arraysimple)
{

  $i = 0;
  $j = 0;

  while (isset($arraymult[$i]))
  {
    // this conditions isnt correct I still dont know why

      if ( ($arraymult[$i]['id_user_sending'] == $arraysimple['id_user_sending'])
      ||  ($arraymult[$i]['id_user_receiving'] == $arraysimple['id_user_receiving']))
        return 0;
    $i++;
  }
  return 1;
}


function rend_moi_une_occurence_par_conv($raw_message)
{
  $array = array();
  $i = 0;
  $j = 0;

  while (isset($raw_message[$i]))
  {

    if (is_not_yet_in_array($array, $raw_message[$i]) == 1)
    {
      $array[$j] =  $raw_message[$i];
      $j++;
    }
    $i++;
  }
  return ($array);
}

$arraytoconvertinJson = rend_moi_une_occurence_par_conv($raw_message);
```

Here the return of function rend_moi_une_occurencence_par_conv so i prionted $arraytoconvertinJson -->>

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 19
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 2
            [date] => 2020-02-19 13:01:53
            [content] => yo
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 11
            [id_user_sending] => 3
            [id_user_receiving] => 4
            [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:27
            [content] => hey dernier test !
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

)
```

I'm pretty sure that my condition in the function is not yet in array isnt good but after 24h on it im looking for some help ..

This is the return i want, so the id of the user which connected is 4, i want get a mult array who contain the last message between him and himself and him and other users.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id_message] => 19
                [id_user_sending] => 4
                [id_user_receiving] => 2
                [date] => 2020-02-19 13:01:53
                [content] => yo
                [msg_read] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id_message] => 11
                [id_user_sending] => 3
                [id_user_receiving] => 4
                [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:27
                [content] => hey dernier test !
                [msg_read] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
                (
                    [id_message] => 15
                    [id_user_sending] => 1
                    [id_user_receiving] => 4
                    [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:27
                    [content] => hey dernier test !
                    [msg_read] => 1
                )
        [3] => Array
                    (
                      [id_message] => 
                        [id_user_sending] => 4
                        [id_user_receiving] => 4
                        [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:27
                        [content] => hey dernier test !
                        [msg_read] => 1
                    )

    )
```

This is the return i want, so the id of the user which connected is 4, i want get a mult array who contain the last message between him and himself and him and other users ( this is not a valid output i just modify value of id user sending/receving for the example).
-->

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 19
            [id_user_sending] => 4
            [id_user_receiving] => 2
            [date] => 2020-02-19 13:01:53
            [content] => yo
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 11
            [id_user_sending] => 3
            [id_user_receiving] => 4
            [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:27
            [content] => hey dernier test !
            [msg_read] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
            (
                [id_message] => 15
                [id_user_sending] => 1
                [id_user_receiving] => 4
                [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:27
                [content] => hey dernier test !
                [msg_read] => 1
            )
    [3] => Array
                (
                  [id_message] => 
                    [id_user_sending] => 4
                    [id_user_receiving] => 4
                    [date] => 2020-02-19 00:47:27
                    [content] => hey dernier test !
                    [msg_read] => 1
                )

)
```

Thank you guys for help, im new here so sry if its not perfectly clearly.

Comment: _“Here the return of function”_ - is that supposed to be what you _want_, or what you are currently getting? I am not sure what you actually mean by _“I want clear this array with only one occurence for making a chat list with only one field by user independently of how message there is between them”_, that could do with a better explanation to begin with.

Comment: Sorry i will trying to explain that better, I still need to improve my english ^^

So what i want at final is that ArraytoconvertInjson contain a field for each conversation who exist between two users

Comment: Show the inputs (you did) Show your code (You did) Show the output (I think you did) But most importantly, (**Show what you want the output to be**) And describe the rules to be used to convert inputs to outputs

Comment: ty for ur fast respond, i put the answer i want to get

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie   Thank's for ur comments and help, im new on stackoverflow ..

Comment: In the desired result you have a message from 4 to 4, but I don't find that in the input? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but this is to get the most recent messages sent to a user.

```
function getLatestMessages(array $messages, $receiverId) {
    $times = [];
    $chats = [];
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        if ($message['id_user_receiving'] === $receiverId) {
            $senderId = $message['id_user_sending'];
            if (!isset($times[$senderId])) {
                $times[$senderId] = 0;
            }
            $date = new DateTime($message['date']);
            $unix = $date->getTimestamp();
            if ($unix > $times[$senderId]) {
                $times[$senderId] = $unix;
                $chats[$senderId] = $message;
            }
        }
    }
    return $chats;
}
```

To get the most recent messages sent from everybody to user 3:

```
getLatestMessages($messages, 3);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 12
            [id_user_sending] => 1
            [id_user_receiving] => 3
            [date] => 2020-02-19 09:03:50
            [content] => Last message from user 1 to user 3
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_message] => 77
            [id_user_sending] => 2
            [id_user_receiving] => 3
            [date] => 2020-02-19 10:03:50
            [content] => Only message from user 2 to user 3
            [msg_read] => 1
        )

)
```

And here is the sample data I used.

```
$messages = [
    [
        'id_message' => 17,
        'id_user_sending' => 1,
        'id_user_receiving' => 1,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 01:03:50',
        'content' => 'Only message from user 1 to user 1',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 53,
        'id_user_sending' => 3,
        'id_user_receiving' => 1,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 02:03:50',
        'content' => 'First message from user 3 to user 1',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 32,
        'id_user_sending' => 3,
        'id_user_receiving' => 1,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 03:03:50',
        'content' => 'Last message from user 3 to user 1',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 72,
        'id_user_sending' => 2,
        'id_user_receiving' => 2,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 04:03:50',
        'content' => 'Only message from user 2 to user 2',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 4,
        'id_user_sending' => 1,
        'id_user_receiving' => 2,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 05:03:50',
        'content' => 'Only message from user 1 to user 2',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 82,
        'id_user_sending' => 3,
        'id_user_receiving' => 2,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 06:03:50',
        'content' => 'Only message from user 3 to user 2',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 145,
        'id_user_sending' => 1,
        'id_user_receiving' => 3,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 07:03:50',
        'content' => 'First message from user 1 to user 3',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 31,
        'id_user_sending' => 1,
        'id_user_receiving' => 3,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 08:03:50',
        'content' => 'Second message from user 1 to user 3',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 12,
        'id_user_sending' => 1,
        'id_user_receiving' => 3,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 09:03:50',
        'content' => 'Last message from user 1 to user 3',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id_message' => 77,
        'id_user_sending' => 2,
        'id_user_receiving' => 3,
        'date' => '2020-02-19 10:03:50',
        'content' => 'Only message from user 2 to user 3',
        'msg_read' => 1
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thank you a lot its working and now I get why my function wasnt ..